# How to use Jackson's JaxbAnnotationIntrospector correctly?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization, jackson

I'm able to generate the XML I want using @JacksonXmlProperty annotations with the default mapper configuration. But my classes are generated by maven-jaxb2-plugin and already have the @XmlAttribute annotations. When I try using the JaxbAnnotationIntrospector it serializes the attributes as child elements. What am I doing wrong?

Expected output: `<problem xmlns="" id="aaa"><description>test</description></problem>` (repeatable with testGenerateXmlCorrect)

Actual output: `<problem xmlns=""><id>aaa</id><description>test</description></problem>` (repeatable with testGenerateXmlWrong)

I can also generate the expected XML using JAXB but this question is how to do it with Jackson using the JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.

Junit test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JaxbAttributeTest {
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(JaxbAttributeTest.class);

@XmlRootElement(name="problem")
public static class ProblemJaxb {
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")     
    public String id;
    public String description;
}

@Test
public void testGenerateXmlWrong() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ProblemJaxb problem = new ProblemJaxb();
    problem.id = "aaa";
    problem.description = "test";
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(xmlMapper.getTypeFactory()));
    log.debug("ProblemJaxb: {}", xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(problem)); 
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="problem")
public static class ProblemJackson {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    public String id;
    public String description;
}

@Test
public void testGenerateXmlCorrect() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ProblemJackson problem = new ProblemJackson();
    problem.id = "aaa";
    problem.description = "test";
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    log.debug("ProblemJackson: {}", xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(problem));
}

}
```

Classpath includes:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.3.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.3.2
- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1
- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2
- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7
- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7
- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7

By the way I also tried configuring the XmlMapper with this:

```
xmlMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(xmlMapper.getTypeFactory()));
```

but that generated even worse output because the root element name was incorrect: `<ProblemJaxb xmlns=""><id>aaa</id><description>test</description></ProblemJaxb>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this problem existed [before](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/6), but was not reproducible by the writers of Jackson. It doesn't seem like the bug report went very far.

I was able to solve the problem by using [`XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/jaxb/XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html) instead of `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I filed a new bug report for it  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/27

Comment: XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector and JaxbAnnotationIntrospector are both deprecated now (in fasterxml.jackson 2.4.3 version).

Comment: @Xdg I don't think so, the class is not deprecated, only the 0-arg constructor is deprecate. You can still use the other constructor: new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance())